# Convert keys and values of a hash to string

Tags: ruby

I need to convert values and keys of a hash to string, in order to correctly prepare it as params for a `Net::HTTP.post_form`. For instance:

I need to convert

```
{:x => [1,2,3,4]}
```

to

```
{"x"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4]"}
```

It's important to convert symbols to string and that arrays are surrounded by quotes.

- `to_json` returns a string and doesn't solve my problem; I need a hash as return.
- the hash may have more keys and values, so I can't hard code `to_s` to each key or value.

How can I perform it?

Comment: Use Ruby's URI class for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about this

```
Hash[ { :x => [1,2,3,4] }.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, v.to_s] } ]
#=> {"x"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4]"}
```

Or on Ruby >= 2.1

```
{ :x => [1,2,3,4] }.map { |k, v| [k.to_s, v.to_s] }.to_h
#=> {"x"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4]"}
```

Or on Ruby >= 2.6

```
{ :x => [1,2,3,4] }.to_h { |k, v| [k.to_s, v.to_s] }
#=> {"x"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4]"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent a well established wheel. Instead Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is a good tool to use:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.com')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( {:x => [1,2,3,4]} )
uri.to_s # => "http://www.example.com?x=1&x=2&x=3&x=4"
```

If you want just the query values:

```
query = URI.encode_www_form( {:x => [1,2,3,4]} ) # => "x=1&x=2&x=3&x=4"
```

---

It really sounds like you are reinventing wheels if you are going to send that through Net::HTTP. Serializing a hash to `{"x"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4]"}` will limit your code to working with only your code. Using JSON, YAML or XML would make your life easier and your code more portable.

JSON makes it easy to move a hash from machine to machine, between languages like Ruby/Python/Java/Perl, whether it is a browser to a server, or client to server:

```
require 'json'
hash = {:x => [1,2,3,4]}

hash.to_json
=> "{\"x\":[1,2,3,4]}"

JSON[hash.to_json]
=> {
    "x" => [
        [0] 1,
        [1] 2,
        [2] 3,
        [3] 4
    ]
}
```

That's a round-trip of the hash, to JSON's representation, back to the hash. The intermediate string `"{\"x\":[1,2,3,4]}"` is easily sent via Net::HTTP.

Comment: But this is different from what I need. As you can see, this method sets `x` with multiple values. I need it to receive one single value; the string `"[1,2,3,4]"`. That's different.